# how to get powerful flavours when spherifying

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, spherification

Whenever I try to create something delicious using spherification I find that whatever has gone in comes out quite bland (I've tried using fruit juices (non-citric), liquers, soups).

When I taste the food before it goes into the salts, it usually packs quite a punch; so, it's quite disappointing when it comes out and has the lovely texture of caviar but no flavour!

Any suggestions / ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing regular spherification, where the alginate goes inside the sphere and the calcium on the outside? If so, try doing reverse spherification instead, so the goopy alginate doesn't dilute the flavor.

Comment: I am doing regular spherification (using sodium alginate I think?) - will reverse spherification give me the 'shell' that you get from regular spherification? If so, what's the benefit of doing regular spherification (if there is one) - thanks :)

Comment: Yes, reverse will give you the same kind of shell. Almost everyone prefers it. The other option is agar spherification, but that gives you solid little gel sphere, not a liquid interior.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know what spherification is, here's [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherification).